# error using \hline in LaTeX not interrupting compiling but maybe I am doing this the wrong way

Tags: latex

So I'm using `\hline` to create some underlines for the heading of a `\section{}` but I'm getting the error

```
Misplaced \noalign.
You have used a \hline command in the wrong place, probably outside a table. If the \hline command is written inside a table, try including \\ before it.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.15     \hline
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{10pt}
\title{Law and Society Notes}
\author{Jack Dwyer }
\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{January 31}
    \hline
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] \hline
        \item Types of law
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Oral Nomoi
            \item Thesmoi
            \item Written Nomoi
            \item Psephismata
        \end{itemize}{}
        \item Distinctions not drawn between criminal and civil cases or judicial, legislative, or administrative cases
        \item Types of cases
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Dikē(Public)
            \item Graphē(semi-public)
        \end{itemize}{}
        \item Sycophant – suck up
        \item Righteous Indignation
    \end{itemize}{}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to paste an image with generated text in order not to try the code =)
At first sight, the rectengular brackets after first `item` and the curly brackets after `end{itemize}` in the end are suspisious.
Try this solution
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371286/draw-a-horizontal-line-in-latex/371469#371469

Comment: @A.Ametov As long as there are errors in the code, there is no point in showing an image of the output. After an error, latex just recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output

Comment: @A.Ametov The empty brackets after the first item are a valid syntax to remove the bullet point and the additional group after `\end{itemize}` makes no sense but doesn't hurt either

Answer (score 2):

`\hline` is for the use inside tabulars. You could use `\hrulefill` or, better, don't manually underline the section but format it appropriatly, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453372

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{10pt}
\title{Law and Society Notes}
\author{Jack Dwyer }
\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{January 31}
\hrulefill
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] \hrulefill
        \item Types of law
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Oral Nomoi
            \item Thesmoi
            \item Written Nomoi
            \item Psephismata
        \end{itemize}
        \item Distinctions not drawn between criminal and civil cases or judicial, legislative, or administrative cases
        \item Types of cases
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Dikē(Public)
            \item Graphē(semi-public)
        \end{itemize}
        \item Sycophant – suck up
        \item Righteous Indignation
    \end{itemize}
 \end{document}
```